# In R, is there a tabular data structure that can have more than 2^31 cells and to which `apply` can be applied?

Tags: r, matrix, apply

I have two character vectors (or factors) A and B that have so many unique values/levels that `table(A, B)` runs into the >2^31 elements problem. What I am looking for is data structure I could use instead of a table that would permit the use of apply etc. Here's an example:

Setting up the workspace and defining one function to help compute KL-divergences:

```
set.seed(1)
log2w0 <- function (values) { return(ifelse(values == 0, 0, log2(values))) }
```

Generating some vectors that will cause the problem:

```
words <-     runif(470000, 0, 1000)
parts <- rep(runif(4700  , 0, 1000), 100)
```

Now, using `table` for this obviously doesn't work:

```
# doesntwork <- table(words, parts)
```

What I am looking for is a data structure to which `apply` can be applied like this:

```
# generate the prior for KL-divergences
Q <- prop.table(table(parts))

# computing KL-divergences, but what would be apply's first argument?
apply(doesntwork, 1, \(af) {
   P <- af/sum(af)
   sum(P * log2w0(P/Q)) })
```

I looked into sparse matrices but somehow didn't get that to work. I tried an `xtabs` approach like this:

```
doeswork <- xtabs(~ words + parts, sparse=TRUE) # 46.7MB dgCMatrix
```

But applying `apply` to it as above crashes R/RStudio when RAM demand reaches >60GB:

```
# do not run:
# apply(doeswork, 1, \(af) {
#    P <- af/sum(af)
#    sum(P * log2w0(P/Q)) })
```

Now, I do have a brute-force workaround -- creating as many sub-tables of a still permitted size as necessary to get all results and then amalgamate -- and it's not even that slow, but I can't imagine that such an overall inelegant solution is what's necessary. Any input would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, parts with zero counts don't contribute to the score (because of the `P *` in the `sum(P * log2w0(P/Q))` statement). So, I think you could works with a `data.table` containing only the combinations with positive counts.

First create a `data.table` from `words` and `parts` and calculate the observed relative frequencies:

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(words, parts)
dt <- dt[, .(n = .N), by = .(words, parts)]
dt <- dt[, f:= n/sum(n)]
```

Not completely sure how `Q` is calculated as `files` is not defined in your example. But this should be a vector with probabilities for each part. So something like:

```
Q <- dt[, .(N = .N), by = parts]
Q[, p := N/sum(N)]
Q[, N := NULL]

#          parts           p
#   1: 190.03249 0.000212766
#   2: 728.84221 0.000212766
#   3:  93.06367 0.000212766
#   4:  23.48784 0.000212766
#   5: 196.24344 0.000212766
#  ---                      
#4696: 557.53115 0.000212766
#4697: 201.16348 0.000212766
#4698:  69.08102 0.000212766
#4699:  60.18344 0.000212766
#4700:  65.33502 0.000212766
```

We can then add these to `dt`:

```
dt <- merge(dt, Q, all.x = TRUE, by = "parts")
```

And calculate the scores:

```
dt <- dt[, .(kl = f * (log2w0(f/p))), by = words]
```

Answer (score 1):

`apply` coerces its first argument to a (dense) `matrix`, so passing a (sparse) `dgCMatrix` can require a large allocation.  I would "manually" split the `(i,j,x)` triplets by row and loop over the resulting groups with `vapply`.

Given your `m`-by-`n` matrix `doeswork` and length-`n` table `Q`:

```r
d <- dim(doeswork)
i <- doeswork@i + 1L
j <- rep.int(seq_len(d[2L]), diff(doeswork@p))
x <- doeswork@x
l <- split(seq_along(i), factor(i, levels = seq_len(d[1L])))

f <- function(k) {
    if (length(k) == 0L)
        return(0)
    p <- x[k] / sum(x[k])
    q <- Q[j[k]]
    sum(p * log2(p / q))
}

ans <- vapply(l, f, 0, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Your splitting-by-row and then 'looping' over the splits w/ vapply is essentially my workaround, but yours is more elegant than mine: I basically split into as many sub-matrices as are needed to stay below 2^31 cells and then do an actual `for`-loop over those -- your solution seems more R-like to me than mine.